# Is it possible to trigger a web service (or callback event) after authorize.net "AUTH_ONLY"

Tags: authorize.net

I want to update the status of the order when the merchant manually capture an Authorize Only transaction. Is is possible? If so, how to do that?

I have gone through the link https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A64 and it is very clear about the "AUTH_ONLY" transaction. But the link does not provide the details about the callback event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the [Webhooks API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html) to create a webhook for those transactions. Specifically the `net.authorize.payment.capture.created` event. Then your system would be notified whenever a capture occurs.